# PHP uploaded files and temp files

Tags: php, linux

I have a webshop, where the user can personalize a product, by entering some text into a form. After he has submitted the text, my server generates a preview image and shows it to the user.

Since I do not want to regenerate the image on every page refresh (it takes to much time), I save the image on the server, with a unique hashed name, so I can just show the image again, as long the session runs. At the moment, I delete these "cached" files once a day by a cronjob.

My question is: Can I just save the files to the /tmp directory, so that I dont need the cronjob and get files deleted on every reboot? Are there any problems with my new solution?

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and php 5.6.

Comment: How often do you expect ro reboot your webshop host machine?

Answer (score 0):

How often do you reboot your webserver?

Why don't you simply create a garbage-collecter that runs automatically when you serve an image, simply check the dates for every image and remove the ones that are stale (older than a certain age) If you worry that might affect performance too much you could also run the garbage collector randomly, say a 1 in 10 or 1 in 25 chance that it runs.

Comment: Basically not so often. But as far as I know, does ubuntu cleans the tmp folder once a day

I know, I can write my own garbage collector (actually, I do it atm, by just deleting all cached files once in the night). I am just wondering, if i can "trust" the tmp folder deletion.

Comment: I found an interesting link here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up/759048#759048

Comment: But basically I would create a folder that has secure permissions and is owned by the webserver, just storing your in /tmp might also cause some unwanted security issues.